# Mathematical expression of energy storage

Tags: material-science, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, elasticity, stress-strain

I'm trying to develop an idea which is as follows.
Put simply, imagine a flat sheet of material which, when distorted (I.e. curved in the third dimension) stores energy. Now, by calculating the components of the Riemann Curvature Tensor to describe the actual distortion, how would you mathematically express the energy stored in the distorted area in relation to the components of the curvature tensor?

Comment: The bending energy of the surface would normally be related to the principal curvatures. I confess I'm not sure how these are related to the Riemann tensor.

Comment: If anyone can map the Riemann tensor to a strain field then I can take it from there...

Comment: Thanks John and Lemon. Would it invove the stress energy tensor?

Comment: Is the energy in a unit area proportional to the total bend (angle, or curvature, or equivalent)?  What if the energy is a nonlinear function of curvature?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some context into the exact physical system you're considering? The statement that "energy is stored" by bending/distortion is very ambiguous, and there are many possible models (free field approximation, nonlinear sigma models, etc.) you could use to describe such a system, and the details crucially depend on which model you use

Answer (score 1):

I may be over-simplifying the problem a bit, but the laws of motion of a flexible sheet are very similar to that of a classical field. And the classical field is described by a Lagrangian density of

$$\mathcal{L}(\phi;x,y,t) = \frac{1}{2} \left[\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\right)^2 - \left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)^2 - \left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\right)^2\right] - V(\phi)$$

up to a few constants to make units work out. And since we have no time variation (I'm assuming you're discussing the membrane not being in motion), we can assume $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}$ to be 0. And we'll change the sign just to keep the math a little simpler.

So now we have a Lagrangian density of:

$$\mathcal{L}(\phi;x,y) = \frac{1}{2} \left[\left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\right)^2\right].$$

And since we're looking for energy, we'll compute a Hamiltonian density from the Lagrangian, which Should be $\mathcal{H} = \Sigma_i p_i \dot{q}_i - \mathcal{L}(\phi;x,y)$. Since we're no longer dealing with time coordinates, we replace the $\dot{q}$ by a $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}$. And our momentum will also be something similar (up to constants to fix our units). So the Hamiltonian density should be something proportional to

$$\mathcal{H} = \frac{1}{2} \left[\left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\right)^2\right].$$

I hope that helps some. I apologize for not including the constants for units, but whatever they are, they should have units of energy per unit area, since $\phi$ is essentially the elevation or depression of the membrane above its equilibrium position, and taking a derivative of position with respect to position, gives a unitless number, and this is a Hamiltonian density which must be integrated over its area.

I'm not too sure that all of that is exactly correct as far as the math goes, but it seemed like the most sensible route to me. Please comment if you have any corrections you'd apply.

Comment: Thankyou JoDraX.....I'll look into this approach and get back to you with any feedback and/or further queries!!

Comment: Currently doing some research in this area, as it's one I haven't previously covered. As "phi" denotes the elevation with respect to various coordinates, is this not equivalent to the components of the curvature tensor itself? If so, this is exactly what I'm looking for JoDraX!

Comment: @KeithYoung The values of $\phi$ are certainly not equivalent to the curvature tensor components. To compute the curvature tensor in this example, you would need to find the "pullback" of the metric tensor, which is essentially the metric tensor of your elastic sheet, and is given by $g_{ab}(x,y)=\delta_{ab}+\partial_{a}\phi\,\partial_{b}\phi$, assuming that your sheet is embedded in flat space. From this you could compute the curvature tensor on the sheet.